# Paint cell background of Table

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt

I have to implement selection to my `Table`, and for that it's necessary to paint the background of a cell in blue (and possible later the foreground white, but that's a problem for the future).

The naive approach was to just use a paint event like this:

```
table.addListener(SWT.PaintItem, event -> {
        final boolean selection = // calulate somehow;

        if (selection) {
            event.gc.setForeground(this.table.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION));
            Rectangle bounds = table.getItem(new Point(event.x, event.y)).getBounds();
            event.gc.fillRectangle(event.x, event.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
        }
    });
```

However that paints over everything in the cell, and I would need to paint the entire content of the table myself. That's not really what I want to do right now.

Then I tried to use `TableItem#setBackground(Color)`, which gets overridden by the pre-made selection and hover colors, even if they are disabled like that:

```
 table.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, event -> {
        event.detail &= ~SWT.SELECTED;
        event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT;
        event.detail &= ~SWT.FOCUSED;
    });
```

So a row that is selected or hovered over is displayed in white by the OS.

I tried `EraseItem` and `MeasureItem` as well in hopes to find an event that gets thrown before the cells are painted so I can only draw the background. But `EraseItem` paints over everything and painting in `MeasureItem` doesn't do anything.

Is there any way to paint the background of a cell without having to paint the foreground manually or getting overridden by the table's build-in selection?

Comment: Is this just `Table` or are you using `TableViewer` - which supports a label provider implementing `IColorProvider`.

Comment: @greg-449 It's a `TableViewer`, but both the label providers on the table and on the columns get overriden by the selection and hover as well.

Comment: For TableViewer I use an extended `StyledCellLabelProvider` to draw a custom selection indicator (and styled text).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As greg-449 said, `StyledCellLabelProvider` is probably the way to go:

```
tableViewerColumn.setLabelProvider(new StyledCellLabelProvider() {

    @Override
    public void update(ViewerCell cell) {
        cell.setText("Content");

        final int column = cell.getColumnIndex();
        final int row = Arrays.asList(tableViewer.getTable().getItems()).indexOf(cell.getItem());

        if (selection) {
            Display display = cell.getControl().getDisplay();
            cell.setBackground(display .getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION));
            cell.setForeground(display .getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_LIST_SELECTION_TEXT));
        }

        super.update(cell);
    }
});
```

This gets overriden by the system's selection and hover until you add:

```
table.addListener(SWT.EraseItem, event -> event.detail &= ~SWT.HOT);
table.addListener(SWT.Selection, e -> table.setSelection(-1));
```

Comment: I am still not able to  understand your question. You want to set background and foreground color of your selected Cell(Cell selected by Mouse or by arrow keys),  right?